# Enable user interaction for textfield on all the visible cells while editing the table view on edit mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a textfield on UITableView cell.

```
textfield = (UITextField *) [cell viewWithTag:34];
 textfield.text = [SadikArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

when the table view is on edit mode I should enable user interaction of textfield to true, and disable user interaction when table view is not in editing mode.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

When your UITableView is in edit mode then in cellForRowAtIndexPath make the User Interaction of your UITextField to YES so that user can interact with UITextFields like this

```
textField.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

also when you make your UITableView as in Edit Mode then reload your table view.

When you set your UITableView is not in Editing mode then make User Interaction to No like this

```
textField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Also, don't forget to reload your UITableView when you make your UITableView non editing.

Comment: Happy Coding :)